# Difference between getAssociatedProductIds() and getUsedProductIds($product)?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I want to get the simple products associated with a configurable product. What is the difference between the following methods and why/when would I use one over the other? Both appear to return an array of IDs, however I have noticed the former is unreliable when used on a new, just-saved product.

Approach 1:

```
$arr = $configurableProduct->getAssociatedProductIds();
```

Approach 2:

```
$arr = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds($configurableProduct);
```